# what does this function do that helps it to take input differently and how are the conditions in for loop executed

Tags: c, function, for-loop

What does this function do that helps it to take input differently and how  are the conditions in for loop executed?

```
void scanint(int &x)
{
  int flag=0;
  register int c = gc();
  if(c == '-') flag=1;
  x = 0;
  for(;(c<48 || c>57);c = gc());//why is this used?
  for(;c>47 && c<58;c = gc()) {x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48;}//how  is this executed ?
  if(flag == 1)x=-x;
}
```

Comment: What language is this? c? Use proper tags, 'function' is not the best choice

Comment: Yes this is in C . I just want to understand the concept of this function and its working.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might replace `48` with `'0'` and `57` with `'9'` for better understanding.

Comment: `void scanint(int &x)` this looks like C++, not C.

Answer (score 0):

It's not c.

```
void scanint(int &x) {/* Whatever */}
//               ^^
```

This defines a function accepting a *reference* to an `int` and there are no references in c, the arguments are passed by value to functions. You could of course use a *pointer* to an `int`, but then the body of the function should be changed accordingly, using `*x` instead of ant occurrences of `x`.

The following assumes that `gc()` stands for a function similar to `getchar()`, so that the posted code is a *very bad* way of extracting an `int` value from `stdin`:

```
void scanint(int &x)   // Or 'int *x' in C
{
    int c = gc();      // register was deprecated in C++17

    bool is_negative = (c == '-'); // C has bool from C99 too

    x = 0;             // '*x = 0;' in C. The same applies to the following code

    // Considering only ASCII, ignores non-digit characters
    // E.g. from "  123" it ignores the first two spaces,
    // but, given " -123", it will ignore the sign too. Bad, as I said.
    for( ;
         ( c < '0'  ||  c > '9');  
         c = gc() )
    ;

    // Now computes the actual number using an old trick that should
    // be left to the compiler to be exploited:
    // 10 * x = (2 + 8) * x = 2 * x + 8 * x = x << 1  +  x << 3 (bit shifts)
    for( ;
         '0' <= c  &&  c <= '9';
         c = gc() )
    {
        x = (x << 1) + (x << 3) + c - '0';
    }
    if ( is_negative )
        x = -x;
}
```